# Progressbar in XHttpRequest does not work

Tags: extjs

I have the following xHttpRequest and trying to get the progressbar working.
The progress Event is triggered. But it seems to be done once and is not updated anymore

```
uploadFile: function (file, progressBar, infoText, count) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
         me = this;

     progressBar = progressBar || 0;
     infoText = infoText || null;

     xhr.open("post", me.requestURL, true);

     xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
         // debugger;
         progressBar.update( { percent: (evt.loaded / file.size)*100 } );
     });

     // Upload complete
     xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
         var target = e.target,
             response = Ext.decode(target.responseText);

         if (response.success == false && response.blacklist == true) {
             Shopware.Notification.createGrowlMessage(me.snippets.blackListTitle, Ext.String.format(me.snippets.blackListMessage, response.extension));
         }
         if (response.return == "check") {

             me.infoMessageBox(response,count);

         }
```

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uploading the file you must listen to xhr.uploads progress:

```
 xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
     progressBar.update( { percent: (evt.loaded / file.size)*100 } );
 });
```

Or like this:

```
 xhr.upload.onprogress = function(evt) {
     progressBar.update( { percent: (evt.loaded / file.size)*100 } );
 }
```

It's better to use `evt.total` instead of `file.size`.
More: [link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I will try it. I used file.size, because evt.total was 0 everytime. Do not ask my why :-)

Comment: Damn. that was it.
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {

thanks for your help !